# vgdisplay not showing free PE / Size space

Tags: centos6, lvs, parted

I have Dell PowerEdge R730xd running Centos 6. I just added more physical disks to our raid and used open manage to increase the raid size, which is now at 67,063.50GB. I'm using xfs and have a lv (lv_vol1a) that I would like to extend using xfs_growfs to use all of this free space. I do not want to reboot the system.

I can see the space on openmanage but I do not see in vgdisplay:

```
[root@crich ~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_vol1
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               36.38 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              9537919
  Alloc PE / Size       9537919 / 36.38 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               2eti0g-2V6p-D8MQ-nG3G-FZoz-hFHz-nxAXbd

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_crich
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               4
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               276.29 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              70729
  Alloc PE / Size       66296 / 258.97 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       4433 / 17.32 GiB
  VG UUID               RN0m1I-8jqV-g1QU-dJud-fifL-vZtc-Z6JE53
```

Here is my lvdisplay:

```
[root@crich ~]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_vol1/lv_vol1a
  LV Name                lv_vol1a
  VG Name                vg_vol1
  LV UUID                zStF5s-HfeL-m4ng-844O-w2Y0-oF6b-WimFpQ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time crich, 2017-09-11 07:54:01 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                36.38 TiB
  Current LE             9537919
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

Here is my parted info:

```
(parted) print free
Model: DELL PERC H730P Mini (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 299GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
        2048B   32.3kB  30.2kB            Free Space
 1      32.3kB  107MB   107MB   primary   fat16        diag
        107MB   107MB   26.1kB            Free Space
 2      107MB   2254MB  2147MB  primary   fat32        boot, lba
 3      2254MB  2779MB  524MB   primary   ext4
 4      2779MB  299GB   297GB   extended
        2779MB  2780MB  1020kB            Free Space
 5      2780MB  299GB   297GB   logical
```

What do i need to do to have xfs_growfs be able to access the free space?

Edit:

I was on with Dell support today. They created a new partition with parted but it still is not recognized by pvcreate. I have to reboot the server which is not something I wanted to do. Any way here is lsblk:

```
 lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                           8:0    0 278.9G  0 disk
├─sda1                        8:1    0   102M  0 part
├─sda2                        8:2    0     2G  0 part
├─sda3                        8:3    0   500M  0 part /boot
├─sda4                        8:4    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5                        8:5    0 276.3G  0 part
  ├─vg_crich-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0  83.2G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg_crich-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─vg_crich-lv_tmp (dm-3)  253:3    0  80.1G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─vg_crich-lv_var (dm-4)  253:4    0  87.9G  0 lvm  /var
sdb                           8:16   0  65.5T  0 disk
└─sdb1                        8:17   0  36.4T  0 part
  └─vg_vol1-lv_vol1a (dm-2) 253:2    0  36.4T  0 lvm  /mnt/data
sr0                          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: You need to change your partition-table, then resize your physical volume. However, I'm afraid that if your RAID grew from 300 GB to 67 TB, you cannot do this with your msdos partition table, but need a gpt table. This will not be easy and it won't work without a reboot.

Comment: My RAID is currently 37T, if you look at the lvdisplay output it says /dev/vg_vol1/lv_vol1a is LV Size 36.38 TiB. I'm seeing anything like that in parted though.

Comment: can you please provide the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: You can try running `partprobe`. But if the partition doesn't show up still, then you will need to reboot the server to continue.

Comment: Sadly I had to reboot. I'm not sure if there is any way to create a partition under these circumstances and not reboot.